# Google list with angle bracket in url

Tags: seo, html, breadcrumbs

Is anyone can help me, how can i make my website that google in search list will show the URL like this (www.ask.com › All › Apps, Gadgets, Computers & Games‎)?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd5VV.png)

Separated by angle brackets, and any part can separately choosen.

Thank You for help!

Comment: I’m not sure, but maybe an [XML Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Those are "breadcrumbs" that Google takes off the text of the page.  To get them into the SERPs you need to have links on your page that are separated by `>` or use the breadcrumb rich snippet markup: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en

Comment: The markup on that page seems to be Google-specific or out-of-date.  It's probably wiser to use [schema.org markup for WebPage](https://schema.org/WebPage), with the `breadcrumb` property.

Comment: This site not use breadcrumbs, but in google it looks like good:
http://www.docplanner.at/kinderarzt/fernitz